# django query: groupby and keep rows that are the most recent

Tags: python, django

I am struggling on a query that is supposed to group by a model attribute and return for each unique value of that model attribute, the row that has the most recent date.

I can't manage to get the output that I am looking for in a way that will be digestible for my template.

here is the model I am trying to query:

```
class Building(models.Model):

    building_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
```

and here are my attempt #1: get the unique projects and use a for loop:

```
projects = list(Building.objects.all().values_list('project', flat=True).distinct())
context = {}
for project in projects:
    proj = Building.objects.filter(project=project).latest("created_at")
    context[project] = proj
```

this is ok but it does not allow me to access the queryset as `{% for i in projects %}` in template => causing pk problems for links

my other attempt tries to get rows, to keep everything in a queryset:

```
projects = Building.objects.all().values_list('project', flat=True).distinct()
proj = Building.objects.filter(project__in=list(projects)).latest("created_at")
```

that only returns the latest entered row regardless of the project name. This is close to what I am looking for, but not quite since I try to output the latest entered row for each unique project value.

what is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with:

```
{% for building in projects.values %}
    {{ buiding }}
{% endfor %}
```

or if you need the project as well:

```
{% for project, building in projects.items %}
    {{ buiding }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use only the latest() without any parameters and will get the latest entry to the table

try

```
proj = Building.objects.filter(project__in=list(projects)).latest()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).